# Прыгает текст в мобильной Opera

Tags: css, opera

Доброго времени суток, друзья.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. В Опере на мобильных при загрузке страницы прыгает текст, то есть когда мы открываем страницу сайта в Опере на смартфоне, то она текст выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при обновлении этой страницы, текст выравнивается следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Опере есть опция "Выравнивание текста", если ее отключить, то эта проблема исчезает. Друзья, может кто-то сталкивался с таким, может можно с помощью CSS или JS как-то отключить эту опцию Оперы по-умолчанию или еще что-то придумать.

**Проблема наблюдается только в Опере, во всех остальных браузерах такой проблемы нет***

Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте на body поставить свойство -webkit-text-size-adjust 100%

Comment: Стоит, но не помогает :(